# The group of automorphisms of a polynomial ring in two variables over an integral domain

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, automorphism-groups

It is well-known that the group of automorphisms of a polynomial ring
$k[x,y]$, $k$ is any field, is a free product of $A(2)$ and $J(2)$
amalgamated along their intersection,
where $A(2)$ is its affine subgroup and $J(2)$ is its de Jonquieres (triangular) subgroup. (Notice that $k$ can be of any characteristic).

For references for the proofs of the above claim, see, for example,
[the introduction in Mckay-Wang's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404988901375).

**My question:** What happens if we replace $k$ by an integral domain $D$
that is not a field?
(I do not mind to further assume that $D$ has characteristic zero).

**Notations:** $Q(D)$ is the field of fractions of $D$,
$G$ is the group of automorphisms of $Q(D)[x,y]$,
and $\tilde{G}$ is the group of automorphisms of $D[x,y]$.

Perhaps from the amalgamated free product structure of $G$, it is possible to deduce a similar structure for $\tilde{G}$? Am I missing something trivial? 
Or perhaps it is not true that $\tilde{G}$
has an amalgamated free product structure?
($\tilde{G}$ is generated by two of its subgroups:
The affine subgroup and the triangular subgroup?).

Any idea will be appreciated.

**Edit:** I have just found (almost) an answer to my question in van den Essen's book "Polynomial automorphisms and the Jacobian Conjecture",
on pages 85-89:
The tame subgroup of $\tilde{G}$, denote it by $T(2)$, which is (almost) by definition the subgroup of $\tilde{G}$ generated by $A(2)$ and $J(2)$, is the amalgamated free product of $A(2)$ and $J(2)$ (Corollary 5.1.3).
When $D$ is an integral domain which is not a field, this $T(2)$ is a proper subgroup of $\tilde{G}$: The Nagata automorphism belongs to
$\tilde{G}-T(2)$ (Proposition 5.1.9). 
(Moreover, when $D$ is a commutative ring which is not an integral domain,
then $T(2)$ is not the amalgamated free product of $A(2)$ and $J(2)$,
see Remark 5.1.5).

**It seems that I can still ask:** Is it possible to find two (or more than two) subgroups of $\tilde{G}$, denote them by $\tilde{G_i}$, such that $\tilde{G}$ is the amalgamated free product of the $\tilde{G_i}$'s over their intersection?

Of course, from the above nice theorems we know that
if there exist such $\tilde{G_1}$ and $\tilde{G_2}$, then they are different from $A(2)$ and $J(2)$.

Comment: I doubt much can be said in general. Even for $D = k[z]$, there is no description (in fact, I was told there is not even any conjectural description!) of the group of automorphisms of $k[x,y,z]$.

Comment: @auniket, thanks for your comment. Is there a known answer to the special case $D=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The tame automorphism group of $k[x,y,z]$ can be described as follows: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~julie.deserti/biblio/Wright_thegeneralizedamalgamatedproductstructureofthetameautomorphismgroupindimensionthree.pdf

Comment: the solution is given by using the Nagata Automorphism.